# multiple versions of jquery with kendo and bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an existing older project that I need to make changes. I have the project referencing jquery 1.7.2 which is used by other custom controls like kendo. I would like to add latest version of bootstrap 3.3.2 (which uses jquery 1.9.1 and above) to the layout of the website  while not messing up with existing code that uses jquery 1.7.2 and kendo controls. What would be an easy way to achieve this.
Thanks for your help.